# How to find farm type stays / internships / volunteering other than via WWOOF?

Tags: volunteering, homestay, wwoof

[In my previous question about looking for "work for accommodation" in South Korea](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/9164/are-there-some-places-i-can-stay-for-free-in-south-korea-besides-couch-surfing), the subject of `WWOOF` (Worldwide Opportunities on Organic Farms *or* Willing Workers on Organic Farms) came up <sup>([▷home](http://www.wwoof.com/), [▷wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WWOOF))</sup>.

It turns out that I've come across a few people who've had negative experiences with WWOOFing as well as those who've had great experiences. Another thing that might put people off is the fee to "join" or "register" or whatever they call it. You don't get access to the list of participating places until you pay this. I noticed that the fee for the Korean WWOOF was $50 `USD`. That's quite a bit for many of us, especially when you're not 100% sure what you're really getting.

Anyway I'm sure that there are similar places where you can stay and possibly help work on a farm in exchange for food and accommodation which are not affiliated with WWOOF so I'm wondering **Are there any other ways to find such farmstay and similar opportunities around the world?**

Comment: Thanks for asking this as a separate question. I don't have any information about this type of program other than WWOOF, so I'm definitely interested if anyone else can share!

Answer (score 2):

I am not 100% sure about the Organic side of things but I've heard that [ProjectsAbroad](http://www.projects-abroad.net/) has this kind of things popping up now and then.

At [WorkAway](http://www.workaway.info/hostlist-PT.html) they at least have some organic stuff going on in Portugal. More extensive search might reveal opportunities elsewhere. I know of Portugal because I've searched for that myself. Never been in contact with anyone using WorkAway. Anyone else got any experience?

I have also heard of [CADIP](http://www.cadip.org/index.html), it is something Canadian I believe. But I don't know any good or bad about that organization. Any comments would be great.